# Why disable stall warning based only on low airspeed, rather than multiple criteria?

Tags: safety, aircraft-systems, stall, af447-accident

One of the factors that potentially contributed to the [Air France 447 crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_France_Flight_447) is that the stall warning was [disabled when the airspeed fell below 60 knots](https://www.bea.aero/docspa/2009/f-cp090601.en/pdf/f-cp090601.en.pdf#page=46).

I understand [why this is](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39742/why-does-airbus-suppress-stall-warnings-in-certain-situations) -- you don't want to have the stall warning go off while the plane is parked at the gate or slowly taxiing.

However, this seems like clearly bad design for two reasons (that should have been obvious to the designers):

1. This introduces an extra point of failure. If the pitot-static system fails, then the stall warning may be disabled due to erroneously low reported airspeed.
2. As demonstrated by AF447, a stalled plane may have very low forward airspeed in an extreme stall.

Moreover, it seems like the solution is easy: Only disable the stall warning if a number of criteria are met. For example, the following logic could be used.

> The the stall warning (based on [AoA vanes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/how-does-an-alpha-aoa-vane-work)) is disabled if and only if (i) the forward airspeed is below 60 knots AND (ii) the landing gear is down/[on the ground](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9456/how-does-the-squat-switch-work) AND (iii) the radar altimeter reports a height of 0.

This logic would still prevent erroneous stall warnings on the ground, but it is more unlikely to suppress "real" stall warnings, as it would require multiple systems to fail.

Alternatively, if you are worried about one broken sensor resulting in erroneous stall warnings, you could require only two of the three conditions to hold for the stall warning to be disabled. That's still better than only one condition.

My question: **Why do aircraft not use multiple criteria, such as suggested above, for disabling the stall warning?**

The point of my question is that you want the stall warning disabled when the plane is on the ground. Whether or not the plane is on the ground should be rather obvious and you should not need to try guessing whether the plane is on the ground based on airspeed alone. There are plenty of other sources of information that can indicate whether the plane is on the ground.

Comment: Where does it say it's a contributing factor? It says that you need airflow over the AoA vanes, and if you're under 60 kts, the AoA reading is likely to be invalid, so there's no way to tell if you're in a stall (pg 44). I think the simple fact is that if you're in the air at 60 kts, recovery is highly unlikely.

Comment: Also, see fig 11 on page 44 and the note. It uses all three measured airspeeds to determine the stall threshold, which is dependent on airspeed. So the idea is to use triple redundancy to always have good data, instead of making up potentially dangerous invalid data.

Comment: @user71659 I’m suggesting _more_ redundancy, not less. AF447shows how triple pitot tubes can all simultaneously fail - they all point forwards and have the same vulnerability to ice.

Comment: You're getting two different things confused. The stall system already takes the worst case mach number (pg 44 note). Increasing the reliability of airspeed instrumentation is a different question. The fact of the matter is, if airspeed is really under 60 kts, then you are dead, there's no reason to warn about stalls in that case.

Answer (score 4):

A review of the stall warning system was recommended in the final report:

> EASA require a review of the conditions for the functioning of the stall warning in flight when speed measurements are very low.

Here is [the outcome](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/206004_EASA_ANNUAL_SAFETY_RECOMMENDATION_REVIEW.pdf) of reviewing the "conditions" (plural):

> EASA has reviewed the conditions for the functioning of the stall warning in flight when speed measurements are very low. The stall warning is designed to be efficient in a realistic and recoverable flight domain. It is also designed to avoid spurious triggering, hence the 60 knots stall warning inhibition threshold implemented on a large number of large aeroplanes. At very low speed (below 60 kts), corresponding to exceptionally high angle of attack, the aircraft flight characteristics are unknown. Flying below 60 knots is out of the flight envelope. Certification requirements are not established to ensure safe flight outside the aeroplane flight envelope.
>
> **Status: Closed — Category: Disagreement**

While yes there are multiple factors in any one accident, the stall warning design was not one of the listed contributing causes. The biggest factor is that the plane *was* stalled by the crew. Tragic as it is.

Adding criteria to a system **adds more points of failure** to that system. As an example, if one RA (radio altimeter) is inoperative, the crew will have an erroneous stall warning on ground that they can't silence. The solution will be to pull a circuit breaker, but this might lead to a flight conducted with no stall warning.

Comment: The proposed logic would **not** cause erroneous stall warnings _in flight_ as your last sentence suggests.

Comment: The quoted text does not seem to consider using other inputs to determine whether or not the plane is on the ground, only airspeed.

Comment: @Thomas - The proposed logic [to me] reads: the stall warning is disabled when A `AND` B `AND` C are met. So if A or B or C fails, the stall is **not** disabled. Nevertheless the conclusion reached via EASA remains and the issue with multiple criteria remains valid. RE second comment: Note that it reads: "review of the condition**s**". Happy to discuss this in chat later.

Comment: The stall warning does not immediately sound when the airspeed exceeds 60

Comment: @Thomas - see update.

Comment: I still don’t understand the last paragraph. The logic I am suggesting will always err in favor of sounding the alarm. An inoperative RA will not prevent a stall warning.

Comment: I don’t see how this is adding more points of failure. The point is to create redundancy. Is having three pitot tubes more failure prone than only having one?

Comment: @Thomas AF447 was caused by continued pitch-up commands because a stall warning did not sound and they did not recognize a stall. Falsely sounding a stall warning can have equally catastrophic effects if a flight crew continues to put in pitch-down commands in an attempt to make the warning go away, ignoring signs of an overspeed. You're setting yourself up for the inverse disaster. You need to fail _safe_. Spurious warnings are not safe.

Comment: @Thomas - Redundancy is having more of the same thing. The last paragraph: for the stall to be disabled on ground, the suggested 3 *different* inputs need to be working correctly and sending the correct signal for the AND logic. If one system is inop (quite normal for planes to be dispatched with inop systems), then the logic collapses and hence the example given.

Comment: @user71659 - From the final report: "The stall warning sounded continuously for 54 seconds". And yet as you say, the crew continued with the pull back on the stick.

Comment: What is worse: a stall warning when you are safely on the ground or no warning while you are falling out of the sky? My suggestion increases the chance of the former but reduces the chance of the latter.

Comment: @user71659 My suggestion would not produce more false alarms _in the air_. So the scenario you suggest is no more likely.

Comment: @ymb1 the stall warning on AF447 was intermittent. While we don’t know what was going on in the pilots’ heads, they were potentially confused by the fact that pulling up made the stall warning stop and pitching down (or neutral) made it appear again, which is contrary to what should happen. The intermittency was because pulling up increased the AoA so as to decrease the forward airspeed below 60 knots.

Comment: @ymb1 My understanding is that the crew had a window of a number of seconds to recover at the beginning of the second stall warning. After that, the situation was not recoverable.

Comment: @Thomas - The duration quotation is from the final report. And the outcome of the system's review is as objective as can be. IMO (as is EASA), I don't see a benefit from the proposed idea, as I already wrote in my answer, the stall warning is **not** listed as a cause. This is my final answer, but let's wait for others.

Comment: @Thomas Yes it would. Look at page 44 fig 11 again. Stall AOA is a function of airspeed. An AOA that is fine at M0.3 is twice the limit at M0.8 The right way is to do what the industry did and train stall recognition and recovery in the simulator. Once airspeed is broken, just stop trusting it. Recognize signs of a stall from the buffet and handling.

Comment: @user71659 I was under the impression that the crew had several minutes to recover, but don’t have a source at the moment (I’m on my mobile).

Comment: @ymb1 yes, the AF447 crew failing to recognize that they were stalled is inexcusable. However, it is also inexcusable for a modern passenger jet at cruise altitude and configuration with no mechanical problems to fail to sound a stall warning because it concludes that it is actually on the ground due to low forward airspeed.

Comment: re: *"if one RA (radio altimeter) is inoperative, the crew will have an erroneous stall warning on ground that they can't silence"* - this can be handled by the weight-on-wheels sensor. Many alerts are disabled on the ground this way.